# JavaFX How to make HBox use only the width it requires inside VBox

Tags: javafx

I have a `HBox` inside a `VBox` and while most questions seem to be asking how to get the `HBox` to use the whole width of the `VBox` it is contained in, I require the opposite. I have buttons inside the `HBox` which constantly vary in amount, thus the `HBox` should continually alter it's size, but after adding a background colour to the `HBox` it's clear it occupies the entire width of the `VBox`, making centring it impossible.

It's currently like the top example, but I need it to be like the bottom example:

[image]

And using

```
HBox.setHgrow(wordButtonsBox, Priority.NEVER);
```

doesn't change anything either..

```
public class CentreStuff extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private Region createContent() {
    HBox buttonBox1 = new HBox(new Button("Button1"), new Button("Button2"), new Button("Button3"), new Button("Button4"));
    buttonBox1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
    VBox results = new VBox(10, buttonBox1);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the alignment of  wordButtonsBox to Pos.CENTER?  Then you don't care about the dimensions of the HBox, since it's visible components will be centred?

Comment: @DaveB That doesn't work well because I have a `Text` element also in the same VBox which IS able to be centred simply with `vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)` but it doesn't centre the HBoxes since they're stretched out...and if I centre the buttons within the HBox as you say, they're not aligned at all with the `Text` element..So that's why I need them to not be stretched out so they can be centred within the VBox. Although the why shouldn't really be important since I should able to stop them taking up the whole width.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If the HBox occupies the entire width of the VBox, and the contents of the HBox are centred, then the contents of the HBox will be centred horizontally within the VBox.  So the centre of your Text element should be directly above/below the centre of the Buttons.

Comment: @DaveB Nothing makes sense in Javafx. I already tried what you said, that's how I know. Try it and see. The centring of a row of buttons in a HBox must be calculated differently to centring a single text element in a VBox.

Comment: @DaveB Think about it, if JavaFX made sense the elements in the HBox would already not be stretching to fit the width of the VBox and I wouldn't have this problem in the first place...or at least there should be a simple and obvious way to make it not do so, but since neither you or I know how it's clearly not simple at all like it should be.

Comment: again - [mcve] required (as also seen by all those _but that's not what I want/doesn't work/doesn't make sense_) layouts do make sense, provided you study them, learn their abilities and stop fighting them ;)

Comment: "There should be a simple an obvious way to make it not do so". [There is.](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#fillWidthProperty)

Comment: Create your layout in SceneBuilder. Use the FXML or SceneBuilder's options to know what to do in pure code. That's what I do.

Comment: @James_D Finally someone answered the question. I see you posted it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways, with slightly different effects depending on what else is in the `VBox`:

1. ```
   results.setFillWidth(false);
   ```

   will attempt to resize *all* the VBox's content to its preferred width, regardless of the width of the `VBox`. Setting it to `true` (the default) will size the `VBox`'s content to the width of the `VBox`, if possible.
2. ```
   buttonBox1.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_WIDTH);
   ```

   will prevent the `HBox` from being wider than its preferred width, so this will keep the `HBox` at its preferred width. This solution will allow other components in the `VBox` to be sized to the width of the `VBox`, if that's what you need.

```
public class CentreStuff extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Region createContent() {
        HBox buttonBox1 = new HBox(new Button("Button1"), new Button("Button2"), new Button("Button3"), new Button("Button4"));
        buttonBox1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
        VBox results = new VBox(10, buttonBox1);
        results.setFillWidth(false);
        return results;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class CentreStuff extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Region createContent() {
        HBox buttonBox1 = new HBox(new Button("Button1"), new Button("Button2"), new Button("Button3"), new Button("Button4"));
        buttonBox1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
        buttonBox1.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        VBox results = new VBox(10, buttonBox1);
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to post this as an answer to include code and images.

Don't bother restricting the size of the HBox, just centre its contents:

```
public class CentreStuff extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private Region createContent() {
    Label label = new Label("I am a label");
    Text text = new Text("I am a text");
    HBox buttonBox1 = new HBox(new Button("Button1"), new Button("Button2"), new Button("Button3"), new Button("Button4"));
    buttonBox1.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
    buttonBox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    HBox buttonBox2 = new HBox(new Button("Button1"), new Button("Button2"), new Button("Button3"), new Button("Button4"));
    buttonBox2.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
    VBox results = new VBox(10, label, text, buttonBox1, buttonBox2);
    results.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return results;

}
```

}

And it looks like this:

[image: Looks like this]

Everything makes sense, and the layout looks exactly as it should.

[Edit: To Text as well as Label to show how alignment still works]

Comment: As explained in my comment to you above, already tried that and it doesn't match up with a text element. Add a `Text` element and you'll see it won't centre the text at all with the text of the buttons. It also doesn't answer my question which was to prevent the HBox from stretching to fill the whole width of the VBox.

Comment: I've added in a Text.  It still works.